# iframe InnerHTML Editing with JS

Tags: javascript, iframe, innerhtml

Is there any way to edit the innerHTML of an iframe after you have used .location?

Comment: Do you mean, after you changed the location to another domain? In that case, no.

Answer (score 2):

If the new page is in your domain, then after it has loaded¹ you can access its .contentDocument property, which is a separate document that refers to the page that you just loaded. If the new page isn't in your domain then you can't of course because that would be a cross-site scripting violation.

¹Typically by waiting for its load event, but your new page can also call a function in your parent page by using the window.parent property.

Comment: How would it be a cross-site scripting violation? It would be editing the values an HTML element located on your own site that was viewing another site.

Comment: If you mean the values of the iframe element itself, then typically it has no innerHTML, because it shows the document that has been loaded rather than its innerHTML. You might as well change the innerHTML of, say, an img element.

Comment: @Eric If you are referring to the parts on another site, then yes, that's a problem. The code from that site can interact with the iframe, and so can your code. You could add a script tag that does something evil on their webpage using the user's credentials.